# The GET request does not pass

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I send a get request and sometimes it returns a response, and sometimes not,and I don’t understand why, but even when it returns, it gives an error `ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: input`

My get request:

```
private string response;
    IEnumerator GetRequest(string uri)
    {
        using (UnityWebRequest webRequest = UnityWebRequest.Get(Host + uri))
        {
            yield return webRequest.SendWebRequest();
            response = webRequest.downloadHandler.text;
        }
    }

   public int GetID(string entity, string identify, string ID)
    {
        int id = 0;
        StartCoroutine(GetRequest(entity + identify));
        var json = ParseJson(response);
        try
        {
            id = int.Parse(json[ID]);
        }
        catch (Exception) { }
        return id;
    }
```

Comment: This is not UnityScript.

Answer (score 0):

you have to wait until the response gets.

Please wait for getting the response and then you need to parse the data. You need to manage API response call. because  **var json = ParseJson(response);** Imedadlity call after  **StartCoroutine(GetRequest(entity + identify));**

Comment: How can I wait for an answer and not react immediately?

Comment: there are many ways to do that you can set a callback or new methods for the same.